# Modifying the vertical spacing of styles in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, styles, line-spacing

I'm trying to modify the styles of Headings 1 - 3 in Microsoft Word 2010 to fit the style I'm going for with the rest of my document. However, I can't seem to figure out (or find on google) how to change the vertical spacing on these styles. I really don't like choosing "Heading 1" and find my text has about 1-2 blank lines between it and the next line of text.

Comment: You need to look at format > paragraph > spacing after (for the headings) and before (for the paragraph following the heading).

Comment: See [How to Apply Styles to Levels of Headings](https://www.uthsc.edu/nursing/research-programs/ORGS/documents/Howto--HeadingsandTableofContents.pdf)